# Print a sentence multiple times after concatenating a list in every sentence

Tags: python

I have a text file having a list of things like

```
HTTP:STC:ADOBE:FLASH-ARGREST  
HTTP:STC:DL:MS-NET-CLILOADER-MC  
HTTP:ORACLE:COREL-DRAW-BO  
HTTP:STC:MS-FOREFRONT-RCE  
HTTP:STC:DL:VISIO-UMLSTRING  
HTTP:STC:ACTIVEX:CITRIX-GATEWAY  
HTTP:ORACLE:OUTSIDEIN-CORELDRAW  
HTTP:STC:DL:MAL-M3U  
HTTP:STC:JAVA:MIXERSEQ-OF  
HTTP:STC:DL:MAL-WEBEX-WRF  
HTTP:STC:DL:XLS-FORMULA-BIFF  
HTTP:STC:JAVA:TYPE1-FONT  
HTTP:STC:DL:XLS-FIELD-MC  
HTTP:STC:IE:AUTH-REFL
```

I want to print lines with each of them appended to end of every sentence, Something like:

```
set security idp idp-policy $policy rulebase-ips rule 1 match attacks predefined-attacks HTTP:STC:ADOBE:FLASH-ARGREST   
set security idp idp-policy $policy rulebase-ips rule 1 match attacks predefined-attacks HTTP:STC:DL:MS-NET-CLILOADER-MC  
set security idp idp-policy $policy rulebase-ips rule 1 match attacks predefined-attacks HTTP:ORACLE:COREL-DRAW-BO 
set security idp idp-policy $policy rulebase-ips rule 1 match attacks predefined-attacks HTTP:STC:MS-FOREFRONT-RCE
```

Code I have written is :
read.txt has the list of elements like HTTP:STC:ACTIVEX:MCAFEE-FREESCN etc.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
text_file=open('read.txt', 'r')
filename = text_file.read().split(',')
f = open('out.txt', 'w')
for elem in filename:
    print f, 'set security idp idp-policy $policy rulebase-ips rule  matchattacks predefined-attacks', elem
f.close()
```

Comment: python2 or three?  I'm going to assume two because of the print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try- `readlines` to read file line into a list then add list elements one by one to that string and write to second file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
text_file=open('read.txt', 'r')
filename = text_file.readlines()
f = open('out.txt', 'w')
for elem in filename:
    #print f, 'set security idp idp-policy $policy rulebase-ips rule  
    f.write('set security idp idp-policy $policy rulebase-ips rule  matchattacks predefined-attacks'+ elem+'\n')
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('read.txt', 'rt') as f:
    endings = f.read().split()

proto = 'set security ...'
commands = '\n'.join([proto + end for end in endings])

with open('out.txt', 'wt') as f:
    f.write(commands)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
text_file=open('read.txt', 'r')
filename = text_file.readlines()
f = open('out.txt', 'w')
for elem in filename:
    f.write('set security idp idp-policy $policy rulebase-ips rule matchattacks predefined-attacks '+elem)
f.close()
```